# How to deploy Flask app as package to App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform

I'm following various tutorials from Google Cloud to try and deploy my first Python Flask application to App Engine. I organized my app as a package instead of a module, after watching the tutorial from Corey Schafer on YouTube titled: *"Python Flask Tutorial: Full-Featured Web App Part 5 - Package Structure"*

So now, in my working directory, I have a structure like this:

```
1. Project folder 
    1.1   myapp folder
        1.1.1   __pycache__
        1.1.2   static folder
        1.1.3   __init__.py
        1.1.4   app.yaml
        1.1.5   requirements.txt
        1.1.6   something_else.py
    1.2  run.py
```

My `run.py` file has the following code:

```
from myapp import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My `app.yaml` file looks like this:

```
runtime: python37

handlers:
  # This configures Google App Engine to serve the files in the app's static
  # directory.
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

  # This handler routes all requests not caught above to your main app. It is
  # required when static routes are defined, but can be omitted (along with
  # the entire handlers section) when there are no static files defined.
- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

Now I am not sure how to set up my `app.yaml` file to specify the entry point, and also make my app run when I deploy it to App Engine. I am currently running the `gcloud app deploy` command via the Google Cloud SDK after I `cd` into `myapp` folder first?

The deployment phase in the console goes well, but when I check the app's browsing link, I am faced with a 502 Bad Gateway error (as I'm also expecting).

Everything works fine locally, but the deployment isn't too straightforward for me now that my app is structured like a package. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `app.yaml`, you can specify a custom entrypoint like so:

```
runtime: python37
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT myapp:app
```

Where `myapp:app` corresponds to the module to import the WSGI app from (`from myapp import app`)

You should also move your `app.yaml` file to be in the project folder instead, and run `gcloud app deploy` from there instead.

More details here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime